# Forked process refuses to exit

Tags: perl, unix, cygwin, fork

I am running the following in Cygwin:

```
my $pid = fork();

if (!$pid) {
    system($command);
    # do other stuff
    exit;
}
else {           
    sleep $timeout;
    print "Process timed out\n"
    system ("TASKILL /F /T /PID $pid");
}
```

If the process times out, it is killed as intended, so that part works. When the process finishes in time, however, and “other stuff” is done, the `perl.exe` then just hangs indefinitely. Why does it not exit?

If I use `exec()` instead of `system()`, the “other stuff” is not done, and it still doesn’t exit.

Thanks

Comment: It still doesn't exit when I take out the "other stuff."

Comment: A Cygwin pid is not the same thing as a Windows pid! Use `Cygwin::pid_to_winpid($cygwin_pid)` to get a value suitable for passing to `TASKKILL`. With a Cygwin pid you should just be using the builtin `kill`.

Comment: hum, how does `fork` work in a Cygwin Perl. Is it emulated by threads there too?

Comment: A failed `fork` returns the undefined value, but your code is not checking for that condition. This is not likely to be the source of your problem, but checking the return statuses of system calls is an excellent habit to develop.

Comment: @ikegami: no, not emulated by threads.  but not as cheap as a real fork either.

Comment: @mob: thanks! that made `TASKKILL` more effective.